# Imagem sem Margem CSS E BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Bom galera sou fraco em HTML/CSS e bootstrap.

Quero fazer um site com imagem de fundo completa(sem margem).Ex > [Exemplo que desejo copiar](https://aperambioenergia.com.br/45anos/)

Porém quando eu coloco esse código bootstrap para aparecer o modal em baixo, cria uma margem automaticamente. >

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Aqui está meu código completo >

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head> <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 
     
 
 
 
     <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
     <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     
    <title>Document</title>
    <body >
          
          <div class="container" id ="c1">
                  
               <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
                     <img src="../Site/logo.png" width=”20%” height=”40%”>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
                              <h3>Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm col-md-4">     
                                
                    
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div> 
           </div>
  
           <body >
    
 </head>
<body >
            
     <div class="container-fluid">
               
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h3> A Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação (FIT), subordinada à Diretoria Financeira (DFI), é a unidade responsável pela gestão dos sistemas corporativos de informação da Aperam South America.</h3>
              </div>
          </div>

     <div class="col-md-12" >
                  <div class="btn-btn-group"> 
                     <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infra" id="infraestrutura">Infraestrutura</button>  
                         </div> 
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target ="#segu" id="seguranca">Segurança</button>

                          </div>      
                    </div>
                     <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target ="#siste" id="sistemas">Sistemas</button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target ="#tele" id="telefonia">Telefonia</button>
                          </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
          </div>
    </div>
     
  



<!-- Modal Infraestrutura-->
<div class="modal fade" id="infra" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="infraLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Infraestrutura</p></h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h4 class ="text-primary" style="text-align:center;"> <p>Componentes ou Plataformas</p> </h4> 
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Hardware:</strong>
  <font color="black">Consiste na tecnologia para processamento computacional, armazenamento, entrada e saída de dados. Inclui, também, equipamentos para reunir e registrar dados, meios físicos para armazená-los e os dispositivos de saída da informação processada.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Software:</strong>
  <font color="black">É dividido em softwares de sistema e de aplicativos. Os de sistema administram os recursos e as atividades do computador. Os de aplicativos direcionam o computador a uma tarefa específica solicitada pelo usuário.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Rede:</strong>
  <font color="black">Proporciona conectividade de dados entre funcionários, clientes e fornecedores. Isso inclui a tecnologia para operar as redes internas da organização, os serviços prestados por companhias telefônicas ou de telecomunicações e a tecnologia para operar sites e conectar-se com outros sistemas computacionais por meio da internet.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Serviços:</strong>
  <font color="black">As organizações precisam de pessoas para operar e gerenciar os outros componentes da infraestrutura de TI, além de ensinar seus funcionários a usar essas tecnologias em suas atividades. Nem mesmo as grandes organizações tem a equipe, o orçamento ou a experiência requerida para implantar e operar a ampla gama de tecnologias que necessitam. Quando precisam fazer alterações profundas em seus sistemas, ou implantar uma estrutura completamente nova, em geral, as organizações recorrem a consultores externos que as ajudam com a integração do sistema. Existem milhares de fornecedores de tecnologias que oferecem serviços e componentes da infraestrutura de TI, assim como um número igualmente grande de maneiras de combiná-los.</font>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
     
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
<!-- Modal Segurança-->
<div class="modal fade" id="segu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="segurancaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Segurança</p></h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <h4 class ="text-primary" style="text-align:center;"> <p>Pilares da Segurança da Informação</p> </h4> 
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Confidencialidade:</strong>
  <font color="black">Procedimentos e políticas que garantem as restrições do acesso a informações sensíveis aos negócios para estarem disponíveis somente para pessoas autorizadas.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Integridade:</strong>
  <font color="black">Métodos que visam identifica se as informações não sofreram alterações durante o seu processamento ou envio.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Disponibilidade:</strong>
  <font color="black">Revisão do acesso á informação para garantir que estejam acessiveis sepre que solicitado por pessoas autorizadas.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Autenticidade:</strong>
  <font color="black">É a garantia de que a informação veio da fonte anunciada, de modo que seja possível confirmar sua autoria e originalidade.</font><br><br>
  <font color="black">A famosa fase <strong>"Se algo não pode ser feito com segurança, que não seja feito"</strong> também se aplica a Tecnologia ainda mais quando se trata da segurança de nossas informações que caindo em mãos erradas podem trazer prejuizos financeiros e até mesmo acidentes causados por ataques HACKERS como foi o caso  recente da explosão do forno de uma indústria Alemã que segue nosso mesmo segmento.</font>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Sistemas-->
<div class="modal fade" id="siste" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sistemasLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Sistemas</p></h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Telefonia-->
<div class="modal fade" id="tele" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="telefoniaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Telefonia</p></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h6  class="text-secondary"> A FITI, Gerência de Infra-estrutura de TI e Telefonia, área ligada à FIT (Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação), é responsável pela gestão da telefonia no âmbito da Aperam Inox América do Sul S.A.
          Sua atuação engloba a gestão da infra-estrutura de telefonia interna (atualização, manutenção, suporte, etc.), a manutenção da malha telefônica, a manutenção das infra-estruturas de video-conferência, a gestão dos contratos de provimento de serviços de telefonia fixa, móvel e video-conferência, o processamento (recebimento, conferência, pagamento, rateio, etc.) das contas telefônicas, o reparo e suporte a aparelhos telefônicos, o estudo de novas tecnologias e a gestão dos projetos afins.</h6>








      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    </body>  
    
    <!-- Imagem de fundo e LOGO -->
     <style>
         
          .container{
         background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/800/520/tech?t=1564670272965); 
         background-size:cover;
         width:100%;
         height:100vh;
         }
   
          .container img {
          max-width:200px;
          max-height:150px;
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
         }
   
</style>
   
 </html>
```

Obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

O seu código faltou carregar o .css do Bootstrap. Além disso, você colocou dois elementos `body`, e o primeiro dentro do `head`.

A estrutura básica do HTML é assim:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Em relação à imagem ocupar toda a largura, troque a classe da div onde ela está de `.container` para `.container-fluid`, e use a `id` `#c1` da div, e não a classe no CSS:

```
#c1{
   background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/800/520/tech?t=1564670272965); 
   background-size:cover;
   width:100%;
   height:100vh;
}

#c1 img {
   max-width:200px;
   max-height:150px;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
}
```

Veja se era isso o que queria:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head> <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 
     
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
     <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
     <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
 </head>    
    <body >
          
          <div class="container-fluid" id ="c1">
                  
               <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
                     <img src="../Site/logo.png" width=”20%” height=”40%”>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
                              <h3>Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm col-md-4">     
                                
                    
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div> 
           </div>
  
           <body >
    
            
     <div class="container-fluid">
               
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h3> A Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação (FIT), subordinada à Diretoria Financeira (DFI), é a unidade responsável pela gestão dos sistemas corporativos de informação da Aperam South America.</h3>
              </div>
          </div>

     <div class="col-md-12" >
                  <div class="btn-btn-group"> 
                     <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infra" id="infraestrutura">Infraestrutura</button>  
                         </div> 
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target ="#segu" id="seguranca">Segurança</button>

                          </div>      
                    </div>
                     <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target ="#siste" id="sistemas">Sistemas</button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target ="#tele" id="telefonia">Telefonia</button>
                          </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
          </div>
    </div>
     
  



<!-- Modal Infraestrutura-->
<div class="modal fade" id="infra" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="infraLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Infraestrutura</p></h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h4 class ="text-primary" style="text-align:center;"> <p>Componentes ou Plataformas</p> </h4> 
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Hardware:</strong>
  <font color="black">Consiste na tecnologia para processamento computacional, armazenamento, entrada e saída de dados. Inclui, também, equipamentos para reunir e registrar dados, meios físicos para armazená-los e os dispositivos de saída da informação processada.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Software:</strong>
  <font color="black">É dividido em softwares de sistema e de aplicativos. Os de sistema administram os recursos e as atividades do computador. Os de aplicativos direcionam o computador a uma tarefa específica solicitada pelo usuário.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Rede:</strong>
  <font color="black">Proporciona conectividade de dados entre funcionários, clientes e fornecedores. Isso inclui a tecnologia para operar as redes internas da organização, os serviços prestados por companhias telefônicas ou de telecomunicações e a tecnologia para operar sites e conectar-se com outros sistemas computacionais por meio da internet.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Serviços:</strong>
  <font color="black">As organizações precisam de pessoas para operar e gerenciar os outros componentes da infraestrutura de TI, além de ensinar seus funcionários a usar essas tecnologias em suas atividades. Nem mesmo as grandes organizações tem a equipe, o orçamento ou a experiência requerida para implantar e operar a ampla gama de tecnologias que necessitam. Quando precisam fazer alterações profundas em seus sistemas, ou implantar uma estrutura completamente nova, em geral, as organizações recorrem a consultores externos que as ajudam com a integração do sistema. Existem milhares de fornecedores de tecnologias que oferecem serviços e componentes da infraestrutura de TI, assim como um número igualmente grande de maneiras de combiná-los.</font>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
     
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
<!-- Modal Segurança-->
<div class="modal fade" id="segu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="segurancaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Segurança</p></h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <h4 class ="text-primary" style="text-align:center;"> <p>Pilares da Segurança da Informação</p> </h4> 
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Confidencialidade:</strong>
  <font color="black">Procedimentos e políticas que garantem as restrições do acesso a informações sensíveis aos negócios para estarem disponíveis somente para pessoas autorizadas.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Integridade:</strong>
  <font color="black">Métodos que visam identifica se as informações não sofreram alterações durante o seu processamento ou envio.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Disponibilidade:</strong>
  <font color="black">Revisão do acesso á informação para garantir que estejam acessiveis sepre que solicitado por pessoas autorizadas.</font><br>
  <strong style ="color:rgba(224,82,6,1);" > - Autenticidade:</strong>
  <font color="black">É a garantia de que a informação veio da fonte anunciada, de modo que seja possível confirmar sua autoria e originalidade.</font><br><br>
  <font color="black">A famosa fase <strong>"Se algo não pode ser feito com segurança, que não seja feito"</strong> também se aplica a Tecnologia ainda mais quando se trata da segurança de nossas informações que caindo em mãos erradas podem trazer prejuizos financeiros e até mesmo acidentes causados por ataques HACKERS como foi o caso  recente da explosão do forno de uma indústria Alemã que segue nosso mesmo segmento.</font>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Sistemas-->
<div class="modal fade" id="siste" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sistemasLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Sistemas</p></h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Telefonia-->
<div class="modal fade" id="tele" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="telefoniaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><p class="text-info">Saiba mais sobre Telefonia</p></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h6  class="text-secondary"> A FITI, Gerência de Infra-estrutura de TI e Telefonia, área ligada à FIT (Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação), é responsável pela gestão da telefonia no âmbito da Aperam Inox América do Sul S.A.
          Sua atuação engloba a gestão da infra-estrutura de telefonia interna (atualização, manutenção, suporte, etc.), a manutenção da malha telefônica, a manutenção das infra-estruturas de video-conferência, a gestão dos contratos de provimento de serviços de telefonia fixa, móvel e video-conferência, o processamento (recebimento, conferência, pagamento, rateio, etc.) das contas telefônicas, o reparo e suporte a aparelhos telefônicos, o estudo de novas tecnologias e a gestão dos projetos afins.</h6>








      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    </body>  
    
    <!-- Imagem de fundo e LOGO -->
     <style>
         
          #c1{
         background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/800/520/tech?t=1564670272965); 
         background-size:cover;
         width:100%;
         height:100vh;
         }
   
          #c1 img {
          max-width:200px;
          max-height:150px;
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
         }

</style>
   
 </html>
```

Comment: Muito bom, me ajudou bastante, mas acho que ainda estou longe heheh Estou querendo fazer um site bem similar a esse aqui > https://aperambioenergia.com.br/45anos/